# Is it possible to retroactively add properties to DB-columns using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When you have a database populated with data, is it possible to add for instance

```
:default => 0
```

to one of the columns, by using for instance a migration in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new migration

```
# Rails 3:
rails g migration change_default_on_column_in_table

# or older Rails:
script/generate migration change_default_on_column_in_table
```

and use :

```
change_column_default(:table, :column, 0)
```

See the [Rails documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! I just found change_column(table_name, column_name, type, options) in the rails doc too. Would using change_column(:table, :column, :integer, :default => 0) give the same effect as your solution? (given that the type was integer from before)

Comment: Hmm, I guess it would have the same effect, but I would try it on my dev DB first - before screwing the production DB ;)